# Mirroring a website like I see it after running JavaScript

Tags: gratis, scraping

My employer has created this wix [website](http://ffzein.wix.com/tycron-web-building) he wants me to replicate it from A to Z, I have done what I could, but some parts are still missing. He created the website and wants to move it to his server.

I tried:

`wget --mirror -p --convert-links -P ./LOCAL-DIR WEBSITE-URL`

And `httrack` nothing works. I want to be able to get clean html, and css and js files, I don't want them all in one file.

Is there any freeware available on windows or linux capable of doing that? I use both OS.

Comment: It seems that this is not really a website but a lot of JavaScript that ends up building a website. To do what you want, you'd need a program that runs all the JavaScript. This does not seem to be a wix specific issue. Maybe you want to rephrase the title to "Mirroring a website like I see it after running JavaScript" or so

Comment: @ThomasWeller i'm aware of the js issue and I changed the title of the website

Comment: When you say he wants to move it to his server, do you mean he wants it to appear to be coming from his server, ie. that `www.myexamplewebsite.com` displays the same site, or does he actually want the files on the other site? It seems as though wix has their stuff pretty locked down, so you'd lose any backend: https://www.wix.com/support/html5/article/exporting-or-embedding-your-wix-site-elsewhere

Comment: @Aeolingamenfel he wants his website `example.com` to appear exactly like that wix site that he created, he's trying to avoid paying the wix premium fee. I tried and still trying to recreate it from scratch by coding but parts of it are hard to recreate. So I'm trying to mirror it. He doesn't care about the backend

Comment: A "mirroring software" is the wrong approach for something like that IMHO. From what you describe, the pages are built dynamically – a mirror would always create static content. You'd need to get the web source 1:1 (e.g. via FTP/SCP). But if the site was built with a proprietary framework that's not available outside its vendor's space, chances are rather bad: even if you get *your* part down cleanly, you'd still lack the framework to render it.